# how to open camera using javascript and html5 in android?

Tags: javascript, android, html

could you please tell me how to open camera using javascript and html5 in android ?
I saw 
https://m.facebook.com/
on my android phone when I click on photo button **it gives me camera option** 
so how I will achieve the same functionality in our application

I saw this

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

but it not work only for me it open only the gallery where I select only image .there is no option of camera

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

You forgot to punctuate the input tags.

Comment: I would add an extra explanation to why this is necessary.